# Loading OpenStreetMap in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, openstreetmap, qgis-3

I've written a processing script using pyqgis 3.4 which works.  The next step I would like to achieve is to load openstreetmaps as the base map from within the processing script.  I can do so easily from the Python Console, but that is not how I want to go about this task.  I have tried three different ways to load the raster layers, and can't find or think of any others.  The code doesn't give errors, but also doesn't load openstreetmap.

````
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QVariant
from qgis.core import (QgsProcessing, QgsProcessingAlgorithm, 
QgsProcessingParameterRasterLayer,QgsProcessingParameterNumber, 
QgsProcessingParameterRasterDestination, QgsRasterLayer, QgsProject)

import processing

class RasterAlg(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    OUTPUT_RASTER_A = 'OUTPUT_RASTER_A'

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def name(self):
        return "RasterAlg"

    def tr(self, text):
        return QCoreApplication.translate("RasterAlg", text)

    def displayName(self):
        return self.tr("RasterAlg script")

    def group(self):
        return self.tr("RasterAlgs")

    def groupId(self):
        return "RasterAlgs"

    def shortHelpString(self):
        return self.tr("RasterAlg script without logic")

    def helpUrl(self):
        return "https://qgis.org"

    def createInstance(self):
        return type(self)()

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):

        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterRasterDestination(
            self.OUTPUT_RASTER_A,
            self.tr("Output Raster A")
            ))

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):

        urlWithParams = 'type=xyz&url=https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png&zmax=19&zmin=0&crs=EPSG4326'
        rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(urlWithParams, 'OpenStreetMap', 'wms')
        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(rlayer)

        view = QgsRasterLayer(urlWithParams, 'OpenStreetMap2','gdal')
        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(view)


        results = {}
        results[self.OUTPUT_RASTER_A] = rlayer

        return results```
````

Answer (score 2):

You mustn't use `QgsProject.instance()` in a processing script. The project is given from the context you are using. You have the `context.project()` property for that.

If you really want to add the layer from within the processing script :

```py
    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        # Add your other parameters and output parameters

        self.addOutput(
            QgsProcessingOutputMultipleLayers(
                self.OUTPUT_LAYERS,
                self.tr('Output layers')
            )
        )

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):

        # At the end of the processAlgorithmn
        # Add the layer to the project

        output_layers = []
        output_layers.append(layer)
        context.temporaryLayerStore().addMapLayer(layer)
        context.addLayerToLoadOnCompletion(
            layer.id(),
            QgsProcessingContext.LayerDetails(
                'layer name',
                context.project(),
                self.OUTPUT_LAYERS
            )
        )

        return {self.OUTPUT_LAYERS: output_layers}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can't add a mapLayer from a processing script, because the processing script runs asynchron/"in parallel" with qgis and can't invoce a new map layer. This is also discussed in [Load layer in QGIS legend from Processing script [QGIS 3]](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/280503/load-layer-in-qgis-legend-from-processing-script-qgis-3)

Comment: It's possible to add layers from a Processing algorithm. Even without the flag `NoThreading`, CF my answer above.