# Processing script returns no layer

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing

I am trying to run a processing script without a user defined layer output. The example below should create a vector layer with one point. The script runs without any error but the layertree is empty. If you run an other script afterwards, for example "Buffer" the layer is available and you can buffer the result from the script below.

What do I miss to make the created layer available for the layertree? My guess is that `QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)` does not work with the alg class? I know that the correct usage of the processing script would be using a `QgsFeatureSink`, but I am trying to do it the way below to get more control over the result layer.

```
from qgis.processing import alg
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QVariant
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsFeature, QgsField, QgsGeometry, QgsPointXY, QgsVectorLayer

@alg(name="test123", label=alg.tr("test123"), group="geophysics", group_label=alg.tr("Geophysics"))
@alg.output(type=alg.NUMBER, name="OUTPUT", label='Number of features processed')
def test123(instance, parameters, context, feedback, inputs):
    """
    tries to add a vectorlayer through a processing script
    """
    vl = QgsVectorLayer("Point", "Hello", "memory")
    pr = vl.dataProvider()
    pr.addAttributes([QgsField("name", QVariant.String),
              QgsField("field1",  QVariant.Int),
              QgsField("field2", QVariant.Double)])
    vl.updateFields() 

    f = QgsFeature()
    f.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(20,20)))
    f.setAttributes(["Hello QGIS", 100, 10.1])
    pr.addFeature(f)
    vl.updateExtents() 
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
    if vl.isValid():
       QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
       out = 1
    else:  
       out = 0 
    return {"OUTPUT":out}
```

[image]

Comment: You can try to refresh your project ```iface.mapCanvas().refresh()``` but I think the problem is more on the side of your v1 layer. Is your v1 layer is valid?

Comment: @Cyril: I use the german QGIS Interface: german word for Buffer is Puffer;-)

Comment: @Vincent: running the part from creating the vectorlayer until adding it to the project runs fine from the console

Comment: Hi @eurojam, I can't fully answer your question, but as I understand it, interacting with the project instance is not thread safe and doing so in a processing script (which run in a background thread by default) can lead to unpredictable behavior. There was a similar question fairly recently (which I can't find now) where Nyall Dawson outlined this in a comment. I'm not really familiar with the new `@alg` decorator style of processing script- I am accustomed to the older style of sub-classing `QgsProcessingAglorithm`, where you can re-implement the `flags()` method...

Comment: ...and return the `NoThreading` flag. It must be possible to do the same with the new style of script (which I think Nathan Woodrow developed) but I'm not sure how!

Comment: Thanks a lot Ben, I've found the thread you talking about: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/278406/getting-layertree-reference-in-processing-script-in-qgis-3

Comment: No worries :-) That's actually a different thread again! But that one looks really useful.

Comment: I've played around with the flags, but did't get it to work with the new style processing script. Using the 'old' style it works if you set the  QgsProcessingAlgorithm.FlagNoThreading Flag...thanks again for the discussion