# Selecting subgroup in Layers panel using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, group-layer

I can select a group layer (for example `C`) using the following script. But I can only select groups in root level (`A` or `C`). I am struggling to select subgroups. I play with the script, but no success.

```
name = 'C'

view = iface.layerTreeView()
m = view.model()

listIndexes = m.match(m.index(0, 0), Qt.DisplayRole, name, Qt.MatchFixedString)
    
if listIndexes:
    i = listIndexes[0]
    view.selectionModel().setCurrentIndex(i, QItemSelectionModel.ClearAndSelect)
```

[image]

How can I select a subgroup (`B`, `D` or `E`) in Layers panel?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Setting the [`Qt.MatchRecursive`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#MatchFlag-enum) flag as parameter enables searching the entire hierarchy of the tree view.

And looking at the docs for [`QAbstractItemModel::match`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#match) it also seems that you put the `Qt.MatchFlags` parameter in a wrong position. It should follow after parameter `hits`, which is a number specifying the amount of search results to look for.

I've adjusted the example script:

```py
name = 'E'

view = iface.layerTreeView()
m = view.model()

listIndexes = m.match(m.index(0, 0), Qt.DisplayRole, name, 1, Qt.MatchFixedString | Qt.MatchRecursive)
    
if listIndexes:
    i = listIndexes[0]
    view.selectionModel().setCurrentIndex(i, QItemSelectionModel.ClearAndSelect)
```